# Who can upvote a question after it was closed?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, voting

I asked [a question that got closed](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77419/scenarios-after-putin) (well, tough).

A couple hours later I received an upvote on it. How is that possible? I may never have tried — can one upvote a closed question?

Comment: The question can even be reopened if enough user with coresponding reputation vote to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone who can upvote a question can upvote a closed question. The only action that is prevented is answering (or taking action to close it I guess) the question all other actions are still allowed.

Comment: Yes, a vote to close is simply a vote to make it impossible for anyone to post an answer. We can hope other thing, but it's strictly a vote for answer-prevention.